# python selenium crawling can't parser in frame (CME Fedwatch tool)

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, iframe

I try to scrap the table in frame(URL:https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/countdown-to-fomc.html)

my code:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Current').click()
sleep(2)
xpath = "//*[@id='MainContent_pnlContainer']/div[3]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]"
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
tabletext = table.text
```

my code can't find frame.

and I try below code without select frame.

```
tabletext  = driver.page_source
tabletext  = BeautifulSoup(tabletext , 'html.parser')
```

but it can't parse content in frame.

please let me know how I can scrap below table.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIHv7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the iframe using following XPath:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,".//*[starts-with(@id,'cmeIframe-')]")
```

Comment: how you can find Iframe id?~